# Code Sign Using Electron-Builder on Windows

Tags: electron, code-signing, electron-builder

I'm having trouble getting code-signing to work on Windows.  I have the following in package.json:

```
"distwin": "ionic-app-scripts build && set CSC_LINK=C:\\Data\\Development\\Projects\\DocsOnTapV2\\build\\dotv2codesign.pfx && set CSC_KEY_PASSWORD=NotTelling && build"
```

But when I run this I always get the following error:

```
Error: C:\Data\Development\Projects\DocsOnTapV2\build\dotv2codesign.pfx  doesn't exist
    at C:\Data\Development\Projects\DocsOnTapV2\node_modules\electron-builder\src\codeSign.ts:45:11
    at next (native)
    at runCallback (timers.js:651:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:624:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:596:5)
From previous event:
    at downloadCertificate (C:\Data\Development\Projects\DocsOnTapV2\node_modules\electron-builder\out\codeSign.js:49:21)
    at Lazy.WinPackager.cscInfo.Lazy (C:\Data\Development\Projects\DocsOnTapV2\node_modules\electron-builder\src\winPackager.ts:42:9)
    at Lazy.get value [as value] (C:\Data\Development\Projects\DocsOnTapV2\node_modules\electron-builder-util\src\util.ts:248:24)
    at C:\Data\Development\Projects\DocsOnTapV2\node_modules\electron-builder\src\winPackager.ts:168:32
    at next (native)
```

It is telling me that the 'pfx' file does not exist.  But it does!  I've tried all sorts of variations for the CSC_LINK variable with no success. What do I need to do to enable electron-builder to find the 'pfx' file?

Comment: Did you supply the .pfx file yourself and are sure it's valid?  If not, open it and make sure it's not a dummy placeholder.

Comment: Yes I purchased the code-signing certifictae, installed it and exported the .pfx file myself from the Certificates store on my Windows laptop.

Comment: I believe that the path with double "\\" is not correctly processed. Sometime the backslash cause problems in the package.json or .js files. Did you try with file:///Data/Development/..etc ? This is what is suggested [here](https://www.electron.build/code-signing)